# SQLSTATE = 23502 occurs on my deployed website. (via Uploading .csv)

Tags: php, database, laravel, csv, heroku

My website is deployed via Heroku (php / Laravel)

I want to upload users on my website via uploading a .csv file.

Whenever I upload users via .csv, it is giving me an error message of SQLSTATE[23502].

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "first_name" violates not-null constraint
>
> DETAIL: Failing row contains (3, null, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2019-05-02 15:00:48, 2019-05-02 15:00:48, null). (SQL: insert into "users" ("updated_at", "created_at") values (2019-05-02 15:00:48, 2019-05-02 15:00:48) returning "id")

I have tried to test my code via uploading a .csv in localhost, it seem to work perfectly fine. But whenever I test it on my deployed free Heroku website, it gives me that SQLSTATE[23502] error code.

**UploadController**

```php
public function index()
{
    $users = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('admin.uploads.index',compact('users'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    //get file
    $upload = $request->file('upload-file');
    $filePath = $upload->getRealPath();
    //open file
    $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
    $header = fgetcsv($file);

    $escapedHeader = [];
    foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
        $lheader = strtolower($value);
        $escapedItem = preg_replace('/[^a-z_]/', '', $lheader);
        array_push($escapedHeader, $escapedItem);
    }
    // looping through other columns
    while ($columns = fgetcsv($file)) {
        if ($columns[0] == "") {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
            $val = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value);

        }
        $data = array_combine($escapedHeader, $columns);


        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $value = ($key == 'role_id' || $key == 'is_active') ? (integer)$value : (string)$value;
        }

        $role_id = $data['role_id'];
        $is_active = $data['is_active'];
        $first_name = $data['first_name'];
        $last_name = $data['last_name'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $course = $data['course'];
        $student_number = $data['student_number'];

        $user = User::create();
        $user->role_id = $role_id;
        $user->is_active = $is_active;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->last_name = $last_name;
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($password);
        $user->save();


        $student = Student::create();
        $student->user_id = $user->id;
        $student->course = $course;
        $student->student_number = $student_number;
        $student->save();

    }
    
    Session::flash('success', 'You successfully created new users.');
    return redirect('/admin/users');
}
```

What could be the causing this error message on my deployed website? I suspect it could be a mismatch between my deployed website's database vs my localhost database.

How could I make my code compatible perhaps?

Thank you for the advanced help!

Comment: you require first_name, but the csv has a row with that missing, so what to you want to happen in that case?

Comment: @tim Hi! I have checked if there is something missing with my .csv file, Here's an example .csv file content that I was trying to upload.


`Role_id,is_active,first_name,last_name,password,email,course,student_number
3,1,Aaron,Fabro,123123,sample@gmail.com,BS IT,2017123456`